# setting a class attribute using a class method in python

Tags: python, oop

I have a class with a few class attributes, that I would like to initialize by using class methods. This is because I have close to 300 items in a list, and I'd rather not have them in the class definition. Since I will be having at minimum, upwards of a few hundred objects of this class, It wouldn't be efficient to read and then create a attribute for each individual instantiation when they won't be modifiying the two lists I've defined, and only reading from them.

```
class exampleClass:

    @classmethod
    def getUnsupportedEvents(cls):
        with open("randomfile.json") as file:
            return json.load(file)

    supportedEvents = []
    unsupportedEvents = getUnsupportedEvents()
```

I want to set the class attribute `unsupportedEvent` using the classmethod `getUnsupportedEvents()`, but when I attempt to do so in the above way, I get the following error:

```
unsupportedEvents = getUnsupportedEvents()

TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable
```

This seems really simple, am I just overlooking something really easy?

Comment: This code should give a `NameError` for `getUnsupportedEvents`

Comment: If you want to assign inside the class just drop parenthesis `unsupportedEvents = getUnsuportedEvents`

Comment: @dhentris that would bind the function to the variable, which isn't what I want. I want it to execute and return the value of the function to be stored as a class attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a class method **before** the class is fully defined. You must delay the call after the definition:

```
class exampleClass:

    @classmethod
    def getUnsupportedEvents(cls):
        with open("randomfile.json") as file:
            return json.load(file)

    supportedEvents = []

exampleClass.unsupportedEvents = exampleClass.getUnsuportedEvents()
```

Comment: If I was to import this class into my main program, would issues not arise as that line of code is outside the class?

Comment: You load modules and import symbols. In order to import the class, the module will be loaded and the line of code will be executed. Of course it has to be in the same module as the class definition after that definition.

Comment: Would the entire module be loaded even if I were to import specific classes from the module, i.e. ``` from exampleModule import exampleClass``` where exampleModule has several classes.

Comment: Exactly. That is the reason why I said *you load (full) modules and import (some) symbols*. In fact `from mod import symb` first loads the full `mod` module and then *import* `sym` in the local (or module global) symbol table.